# Expected value of minimum of discrete uniform random variables

Tags: probability

Let $m,n$ be positive integers. Consider $X_1, \dots, X_n$ iid uniform discrete random variables taking values over the set of $mn$ integers $\{0,1,2,\dots,mn-1\}$. Let $Y_n=\min\{X_1,\dots, X_n\}$. What's the expected value of $Y_n$? I'm more than OK with asymptotics for large $n$.

Comment: I think that, for large $n$, it should be close to $1/(1-\mathrm{exp}(-1/m)) - 1$ because of a rather sketchy argument proving that $Y_n$ convergences in distribution to a shifted geometric random variable with mean $1-\mathrm{exp}(-1/m)$ and daringly assuming that that is enough to make expected values converge, too.

Comment: That, by the way, agrees with numerical evidence.

Comment: My first approximation was $\int\limits_0^{mn} \left(1-\frac{y}{mn}\right)^n\, dy = \frac{mn}{m+1} \to m$ but no doubt it is possible to better than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $\mathbb{E}[Z] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Z \geq k)$ for any non-negative integer-valued random variable $Z$. Applying this to $Y_n$,

$$ \mathbb{E}[Y_n]
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y_n\geq k)
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X_1\geq k)^n
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{k}{mn}\right)_+^n, $$

where $x_+ = \operatorname{ReLU}(x) = \max\{0, x\}$ stands for the positive part of $x$. Then by utilizing the bound $1-x\leq e^{-x}$, we note that each summand is bounded by $e^{-k/m}$. Since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-k/m} < \infty$, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to obtain

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}[Y_n]
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{k}{mn}\right)^n
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-k/m}
= \frac{1}{e^{1/m} - 1}, $$

which coincides with OP's prediction.